# get csv values from two coloumns mysql csv using php

Tags: php, mysql

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DIBgK.png)

Refer Image

I have values like this in mysql.

I need wholesaletl name based on wholesaletlcontact.

Example: when I have value ajin3 then i need the value 1234587452

Comment: Storeing values as CSV is very bad db design.

Comment: I agree with Jens. Each csv list should be stored in its own table. When you want to access that information you can join the user table to the csv tables. Some of the reasons why it's not good to use csv values in a cell are because it's harder to search on, indexes won't be used (making it slower to search on), and also because there's nothing to prevent someone from entering bad syntax, which corrupts the list. For example, if you have "bill,ted" and someone changes it to "bill/ted" your code won't find results for either "bill" or "ted".

Answer (score 1):

Get the field values from db.
Explode them to an array.

```
$myString = "ajin1,ajin3,ajin2";
$myArray = explode(',', $myString);
print_r($myArray);
```

Do the same for the other field values.

Output will be: Array ( [0] => ajin1 [1] => ajin3 [2] => ajin2 )

Then get the id for a specific value:

```
$key = array_search('ajin3', $myArray);
```

And that Id will correspond to the required value in the other array.

Answer (score 0):

Here could be the solution for you

`$wholesaletl=explode(",",$record->wholesaletl);
    $wholesaletlcontact=explode(",",$record->wholesaletlcontact);
    $wholesaletlcontact_arr=array();
    if(count($wholesaletl) > 0){
        foreach($wholesaletl as $key => $value){
            $wholesaletlcontact_arr[$value]=$wholesaletlcontact[$key];
        }
    echo $wholesaletlcontact_arr["ajin3"];`

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have a choice about using the csv files or if you don't feel that the drawbacks matter, the following code should help you with accessing the information:

```
function get_contact_from_name($name, &$name_array, &$contact_array) {
    $name_index = array_search($name, $name_array);

    // Name is not in csv list
    if ($name_index === false) {
        echo "Name does not exist: $name<br />";
        return null;
    }

    // There is no contact in the corresponding postion
    if (!isset($contact_array[$name_index])) {
        echo "Contact does not exist at position: $name_index<br />";
        return null;
    }

    return $contact_array[$name_index];
}

$names = 'bill,george,sophia,marge';

$wholesaleltnames = str_getcsv("bill,george,sophia", ",");
$wholesaleltcontacts = str_getcsv("123,456", ",");

foreach (explode(',', $names) as $name) {
    $c = get_contact_from_name($name, $wholesaleltnames, $wholesaleltcontacts);
    if ($c) {
        echo "Contact: $name, $c<br />";
    }
}
```

You will need to modify it to fit your needs. For example, it would need to be updated to use the row returned from mysql and to handle errors properly.